# Check if no data is left to be sent with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I'm doing is trying to auto load data from the database using AJAX and PHP. So far, everything is working except for the div that checks if all data has been sent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var limit = 50;
    var start = 0;
    var action = 'inactive';
    function load_quote_data(limit, start)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{limit:limit, start:start},
            cache:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#load_quotes').append(data);
                if(!$.trim(data))
                {
                    $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn-info'> No Data Found </button>");
                    action = 'active';

                }
                else 
                {
                    $('#load_data_message').html("<button type='button' class='btn-info'> Please Wait... </button>");
                    action = 'inactive';
                }
            }
        })
    }

    if (action == 'inactive')
    {
        action = 'active';
        load_quote_data(limit, start);
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_quotes").height() && action == 'inactive')
        {
            action = 'active';
            start = start + limit;
            setTimeout(function() {
                load_quote_data(limit, start);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Whenever I reach the end the button still says, "Please Wait...". I tried going to similar questions but none of the solutions were working for me. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider looking at WebSockets they are way more efficient then what you're doing now.

Setup something like a node.js express server that handles your database via REST.